# Access violation at address 5000D0C4 in module rtl140.bpl

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

He compilado un paquete de delphi 6 en delphi 2010, logro compilar, pero al instalar tengo ese mensaje,

al usar los componentes en aplicación o al abrir de nuevo el delphi, me muestra el mismo error

Comment: Usas librerias de terceros para la aplicacion ?

Comment: Suigero que intentes crear una instancia del componente por código, ejecutes tu aplicación desde el depurador del Delphi y veas dónde se está dando el error. Al final, un componente, salvo pocas cosas, no es más que la misma programación de siempre. Al depurar el `AccessViolation`, casi seguro, verás de inmediato cuál es el problema y ya podrás pensar cómo resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Comentas que al *"usar los componentes en la aplicación te da el mismo error"*.
Esa es tu mejor oportunidad para poder encontrar el error. Entiendo que tienes acceso a los fuentes de ese paquete:

1. Si **no tienes acceso al código fuente**, no tienes nada que hacer y tendrás que dirigirte al propietario de ese paquete para que te ayude.
2. **Si tienes acceso al código fuente**, debes configurar en las opciones del IDE el path donde se encuentra el código fuente del paquete para poder realizar "Debug".

Si ejecutas tu programa en **modo Debug** y tienes acceso al códgo, deberías llegar al error y acceder al fuente del paquete para ver qué está pasando.

El error puede ser debido a muchas cosas (es un acceso a memoria incorrecto). Una vez llegues a ese punto y sepas qué linea te da el problema, puedes añadir cual y podemos concretar más sobre el error.